# log file location in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr server (linux) and sometimes it stops automatically.  Can somebody please tell me where i can find the log files?

Comment: depends on how it was configured.

Comment: How do you start Solr? Are you using the start.jar in the example folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are using start.jar in example directory, there is a logs directory under example

Comment: I am using start.jar in example directory and the logs directory is empty even after I have used the search and gotten error messages in the browser.

Answer (score 20):

> By default, Solr log messages will be written to `server/logs/solr.log`
>   and to stdout (console).

Check `log4j.properties` filed under your `Solr root/resources` and set the `solr.log` property to the location where you want Solr to write log files.

Solr also provides logging UI via web. Logging UI is available under *Logging* menu item, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging
```

. Additional documentation can be found here: [Configuring Logging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging).

Comment: This should be at the top.

Answer (score 4):

There is `solr.log` file under `/var/log/` folder.
It records all the `solr` related logs.

```
tail-f /var/log/solr.log
```

As I have upgraded my solr from 4 to 6 on centos 7
Now log file location is different. 
I have log file at /var/solr/logs/solr.log

to see log use:

```
 sudo tail -f /var/solr/logs/solr.log
```

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how your Solr is installed and configured. If you've used the Solr installation script you will end up with the default configuration and in such case, your Solr logs will be stored in `/var/logs/solr`.

It is also possible that the log files location was changed. To see where they are located see the `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` and find the `SOLR_LOGS_DIR` property there. It will point you to the location of your Solr log files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tomcat:

> /var/log/tomcat6

Answer (score 0):

Floowing is the path of SOLR log directory
Suppose $SOLR_HOME is the name of solr directory where you have start.jar file. then

```
$SOLR_HOME/logs
```

Incase, if there is no file in this directory then please change logging in solr. It may be set to console  iun your case

Comment: Not elaborative but generic one

Answer (score 0):

To check solr log file in ubuntu

Open terminal ad go below location

`/opt/solr/server/logs`

Write below command to check live log

`tail -f solr.log`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Solr` Version: `Apache Solr 8.9.0`

You could use two ways to check log files in Solr.

**1). Via the Solr Administration User Interface**

Go to Solr Admin UI and click the link for "`Logging`". Then you will see log info.

Selecting the Level link on the left, you see the hierarchy of classpaths and classnames for your instance.

**2). Locate where the Apache Solr instance is installed in Linux.**

Go to <SOLR_INSTALLED_LOCATION>/server/resources/log4j.properties

Check the **field** --> `SOLR_LOGS_DIR`

Go to that location and you can see the logs being generated there.

Note: By default, `Solr` log messages will be written to `SOLR_LOGS_DIR/solr.log`